# The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, html, apache, codeigniter

While hosting a Apache CodeIgniter website on my server, the first page is coming through fine and the other links are showing an error as shown below.

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /site/ourservices was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
> use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

How to sort this out? I am a beginner.

Comment: Your webserver might be incorrectly configured to handle URL rewriting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add these lines to ***.htaccess***: (based on [codeigniter urls docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file))

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 5):

i will help to you .. i have faced this problem few days ago ..
try to include below code in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines in your .htaccess (your project root directory):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /yoursite

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: RewriteBase /your-site-directory (if not the apache default)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `Site.php` Controller in your `/application/controllers` folder?

Or, do you have a route that points to an existing Controller/function?

Follow either of the following two methods:

1. Create a Controller, and name is `/application/controller/Site.php`. You can copy the `Welcome.php` Controller for quick file creation. Then change the name of the Class to `Site` instead of `Welcome`. Now, add a function in there and name it `public function ourservices()`

-or-

2. Go to your `/application/config/routes.php` file and add a route in there that checks "site/ourservices" and point it to some function in an existing controller. i.e. `$route['site/ourservices'] = 'Welcome/ourservices';`, as long as you have function called `public function ourservices()` in your `/application/controllers/Welcome.php` controller.

In the newly created function in your controller, call the appropriate view: `$this->load->view('location/of/view/file')` which would try to load an existing file `/application/views/location/of/view/file.php`. Make sure this file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Open "000-default.config" in editor, file available in "/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf" and change "AllowOverride" from "None" to "All":

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then save and **restart your Apache server**. If after doing this not opening your page then check if your Apache rewrite module is enabled or not. If not enabled then run this command in terminal

1. `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
2. `sudo service apache2 restart`

then check your page.

Answer (score 0):

Save and restart your Apache server. If after doing this not opening your page then check if your Apache rewrite module is enabled or not. If not enabled then run this command in terminal

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, edit you answer in order to show the code that is currently hidden, make sure to check code appears in the preview